# how value passed into handleChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi I am now studying react and js. I am playing around with the Table Component demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hier2?file=/demo.js:5301-5317

So in the demo, it defines:

```
  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };
```

and then it is used here(line 164):

```
onChangePage={handleChangePage}
```

so I think this is used to change page. but one thing, in the **handleChangePage** definition, it has newPage varible, but when it used in onChangePage={handleChangePage}, nothing passed in.
so how the variable passed?
shouldn't it be like:

```
onChangePage={() => handleChangePage(newPage)}
```

??

If I have multiple tables, and want to pass an index to the change function,
like:

```
  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage, index) => {
   // index to identify different tables that is being changed
  };
```

how  do I use the function?
do I still do:

```
onChangePage={handleChangePage}
```

this way, i think it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The component that accept the `onChangePage` prop (`TablePagination` in this case) is responsible of invoking the handler, which means it responsible for passing the parameters.

With this line

```
onChangePage={handleChangePage}
```

We are passing a reference of a function to `TablePagination` and it will invoke this function while passing it the relevant values.

But when we pass it like this

```
onChangePage={() => handleChangePage(newPage)}
```

That means that we (the parent component) is responsible of passing the parameters, and if you double check your example you will see that it would break, as we don't have any `newPage` variable declared in this scope.

I guess what you meant to do, was this:

```
onChangePage={(event, newPage) => handleChangePage(event, newPage)}
```

Which should work just fine, but when the function we pass has the same signature as the inner function that we invoke then this is useless (unless we have some extra logic to run). So we can just basically pass the function directly as in the first example.

Comment: so what if I want to pass other parameters, like ```index```. the only way is onChangePage={(event, newPage, index) => handleChangePage(event, newPage, index)}, is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure where `index` is declared but if you got some variables you want to pass and you got access to them in this scope then you can pass them with no problems (make sure you update your `handleChangePage` signature of course). So yeah, this is correct if indeed TablePagination is returning that index variable, but again, if it does you don't need to explicitly pass it like that. You can just update handleChage's signature and pass it's reference

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not passing anything. newPage comes as injected argument by TablePagination component (the arguments being event and a numerical input corresponding to the new page). If you want to re-fact it you may do this:

```
onChangePage={(event, newPage) => setPage(newPage)}
```

Answer (score 1):

basically, you passing the reference of your handler to the `TablePagination` component and that component invokes the function at some point in time (clicking on the next or prev page). So It by it self going to pass some extra arguments in your reference function whenever it's being invoked(the page number in your case) and if you check the type definition files for that specific component you will see this:

````
declare const TablePagination: OverridableComponent<TablePaginationTypeMap<
  {},
  React.ComponentType<TablePaginationBaseProps>
>>;



// and going to `TablePaginationTypeMap` will show you the `onChangePage` handler that passess the page number variable into your refrence function like below: 




export interface TablePaginationTypeMap<P, D extends React.ElementType> {
  props: P &
    TablePaginationBaseProps & {
      ActionsComponent?: React.ElementType<TablePaginationActionsProps>;
      backIconButtonText?: string;
      backIconButtonProps?: Partial<IconButtonProps>;
      count: number;
      labelDisplayedRows?: (paginationInfo: LabelDisplayedRowsArgs) => React.ReactNode;
      labelRowsPerPage?: React.ReactNode;
      nextIconButtonProps?: Partial<IconButtonProps>;
      nextIconButtonText?: string;
      onChangePage: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | null, page: number) => void;  <<<<<<<------ check here
      onChangeRowsPerPage?: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>;
      page: number;
      rowsPerPage: number;
      rowsPerPageOptions?: Array<number | { value: number; label: string }>;
      SelectProps?: Partial<SelectProps>;
    };
  defaultComponent: D;
  classKey: TablePaginationClassKey;
}```

Overall, the `TablePagination` component will pass the page number to your function internally and you will have it in your arguments list of your function.
````